# I am trying update multiple rows using values is this correct?

Tags: php, mysql

$query = "UPDATE INTO `Sanctions` SET (`idNumber`, `lastName`,`firstName`, `section`,`sanction`,`expireDate`) VALUES('$idNumber','$lastName', '$firstName','$section','$sanction', '$dueDate') WHERE id= '$id'";

Comment: you're using the wrong syntax.

Comment: You are mixing UPDATE and INSERT. Read the basics of SQL syntax.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Wrong

```
$query = "UPDATE INTO Sanctions 
          SET (idNumber, lastName,firstName, section,sanction,expireDate) 
          VALUES('$idNumber','$lastName', '$firstName','$section','$sanction', '$dueDate') 
          WHERE id= '$id'";
```

## Correct way:

```
$query = "UPDATE Sanctions 
          SET idNumber = '{$idNumber}', 
              lastName = '{$lastName}', .... 
          WHERE id = '{$id}'";
```

The INTO command is not valid for UPDATE query. You need to assign the table equals to (=) values for every column you want to edit.

## Notes:

These query are not well secured, please use prepared statement insted. :)